# How can I create a function that creates a dataframe from another dataframe using certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example this is the dataframe I am starting with called df1

```
       shoe       brand         price
0     Jordan       1             50
1     Kyrie        1             75
2     Harden       2             50
3     Kobe         1             50
4     Curry        3             75
```

I now want to create a function that takes the dataframe, the brand column, and the price column to return a new dataframe. This is what I am working with so far:

```
def dfFunction(dataframe, shoeBrand, priceShoe):
     df2 = dataframe["shoeBrand","priceShoe"]
```

And this is how it would work:

```
print(dfFunction(df1, 1, 50)

     shoe     brand     price
0   Jordan      1         50
1   Kobe        1         50
```

So basically I want to create a new dataframe that takes the brand and price into consideration when creating a new dataframe using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, using `.query`:

```
def dfFunction(df, shoeBrand, priceShoe):
    return df.query(f"brand == {shoeBrand} & price == {priceShoe}")


print(dfFunction(df1, 1, 50))
```

Prints:

```
     shoe  brand  price
0  Jordan      1     50
3    Kobe      1     50
```